# Character equivalence in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, character

I need a way to make a character equal to another character, so i can perform equality operations on it. E.g

```
4 = A
1 = I
if "h1y4" == "hiya":
    [do some stuff]
```

What i cant use:

- var.replace()
- a second if statement

What i need:

- To make one character equivillent to another in for equality operations

If anybody could help that would be great. If its at all relivent this is for a moderation program for chats.

Comment: Is the equal `==` oeprator needed? I would make a `special_equal` function which take the two elements to compare then perform the operation you need

Comment: @lucG that didnt occur to me... Thats the solution! Make that an answer so i can give you a vote and mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `special_equal` function which take the two elements to compare and perform the operations you need.

```
def special_equal(elm1, elm2):
    if elm1 == elm2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And then replace the `==` operator by your new function:

```
# 4 = A
# 1 = I
if special_equal("h1y4", "hiya"):
    [do some stuff]
```